# SDL GUI buttons: how to properly detect hover?

Tags: sdl

I'm looking for an efficient and performant way of detecting a "hover" event on SDL surfaces. Is there any example of detecting button events on SDL?

Comment: [Lazy Foo got a lesson on that](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson09/)

Comment: I mean a more elegant way of detecting hover.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the shape of the buttons will be.

### Option 1

This is the simplest way. If your buttons are rectangular, and there are less than few hundred on the screen, you can use a simple rect collide function. Where for each button, you check if the point lies in the rect that is on the screen.

### Option 2

In this approach, you need to create a new surface, that will have the other buttons drawn in different colors. Then you can check if the pixel under a mouse belongs to a button, and with the aid of a dictionary, find which one it really is. This approach is a bit more complicated, but you can have buttons of any size and shape.

Comment: That library hasn't been updated in a while and it's for pascal. If in your first case the interface doesn't change much you can sort the rectangles and implement a search algorithm to handle it much much faster and faster is always better :).

Comment: @Xonar well, only if you see a difference

Comment: What if i want per-pixel detection?

Comment: that's what the second approach is for. The resulting surface will have different colored pixels, for example all red pixels will be button 1. So the shape could be anything